# Why do we need Django REST framework since Django templates are available?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a question about the REST API and would be thankful if you could help me with it.

As we know, Django provides a template engine along with template tags to include python data types inside a HTML file to present the data to the user. The output will be an HTML file that is sent to the client through HTTP and the browser renders the HTML and presents the data to the user. Keeping this in mind, it is somewhat unclear to me why we actually need a REST API. Under what conditions do users prefer to receive a JSON file instead of a HTML file? I know that JSON files have some advantages over HTML, but what I don't understand is when it is needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The common cases for using DRF are:

1. You're creating a public-facing external API for third-party developers to access the data in your site, and you want to output JSON they can use in their apps rather than HTML.
2. You're doing mobile development and you want your mobile app to make GET/PUT/POST requests to a Django backend, and then have your backend output data (usually as JSON) to the mobile app. Since you don't want to pass back HTML to the mobile app, you use DRF to effectively create a REST API that your mobile app can call.
3. You're creating a web app, but you don't want to use the Django templating language. Instead you want to use the Django ORM but output everything as JSON and have your frontend created by a JavaScript MVC framework such as React, Backbone, AngularJS, etc. In those cases, you can use DRF to output JSON that the JavaScript framework can process.